# LaTeX book template [Font?]

Tags: fonts, books

Does someone have a template for http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Ax-books/Disk_01/Gromov-Metric-structures-Riemann-non-Riemann-spaces.pdf ?

This is also the font style used in Melrose's book on the Atiyah-Patodi-Singer index theorem.

Comment: That looks like a nearly unmodified use of the standard book class. Perhaps you should ask about specific aspects of the design that you are unable to replicate.

Comment: @DonHosek The font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font is bolded. You can accomplish it with both pdflatex and xelatex. For pdflatex, use `pdfrender` package. For xelatex, use `FakeBold` option in `\fontspec` package. Here is a solution for xelatex.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}

\usepackage[]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[
    FakeBold=2,
]

\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}[
    FakeBold=2,]

\begin{document}
    This document has fake bold font.
        \begin{align*}
            a^{2}+b^{2}
                & = c^{2}
        \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Here is a solution for pdflatex. Note: Pdfrender does not work with xelatex

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}

\usepackage{pdfrender, xcolor}
\pdfrender{StrokeColor=black,LineWidth=.4pt,TextRenderingMode=2}

\begin{document}
    This document has fake bold font.
        \begin{align*}
            a^{2}+b^{2}
                & = c^{2}
        \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was after, but this looks nice too

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you won't be happy with the answer.

The font used is the standard Computer Modern, but in bitmap format. This is evident if we look at the PDF file at high resolution. Here's a close-up of the title page:

[image]

where the pixelated shape is very clear. Here's the same with the Type1 version:

[image]

You can clearly see that the font is the same Computer Modern Bold (for the title).